# Inheritance question / problem

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance

I'm creating a custom Layout for android.
The layout implementation is exactly the same, but once I need to extend from RelativeLayout, and once from LinearLayout.

```
class Layout1 extends LinearLayout {
// methods and fields
}

class Layout2 extends RelativeLayout {
// the same EXACT methods and fields
}
```

How can I use inheritance to avoid code duplication and implement my methods once.

Comment: I don't think you want to avoid DRY...

Comment: @Jason yes, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if it will fit your use case, but you might consider using delegation by adding a field of the "other" class.

I am pessimistic though as tha classes are too closely related.

Answer (score 2):

You could use composition and something like the "strategy" pattern:

```
class YourLayout extends ViewGroup {
    ViewGroup strategy;
    public YourLayout( Condition someCondition ) {
       if( someCondition.useLinear() ) {
            strategy = new LinearLayout(); // or Layout1
       } else {
            strategy = new RelativeLayout();
       }
    }
    public View findFocus() {
        return strategy.findFocus();
    }
    .... rest of the methods:
    / rest of specific EXACT methods and fields
 }
```

You may even change the `strategy` at runtime.

This way your `YourLayout` class may use both scenarios.

Comment: And if this is too complicated for your purposes, i would suggest implementing an abstract ViewGroup that contains all of the common behaviors, and then have your two layouts extend the abstract ViewGroup with their specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I used delegation, although somewhat differently. The only overloaded method I have in my class was an overloaded dispatchDraw. So I moved it to a different class and included an instance of it in each of the classes that extend.

```
 class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
        MyDraw md = new MyDraw();

        @Override
        protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {    
            md.draw(canvas);
            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        }
 }

 class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
      //    as above
 }
```

Although I still have two classes that extend, but I'm not duplicating the code that was duplicated before which was what I wanted to achieve.